# Find the correct value using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a simple football pool administrative tool. The goal is to find the closest Tie Breaker choice (B3:B18) from Only the players that have the Highest Number of Correct Picks (C3:C18), compare it to the Final Total of 27 (B20) and display the Name of the Player (A3:A18) in (C22).
In this case, the choices should be between the three players with 12 correct picks, and the closest Tie Breaker to 27 is K's FB Lab.

I've used the following formula:

```
=INDEX(A3:A18,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B3:B18-B20)), ABS(B3:B18-B20),0))
```

It gives me the closest match but doesn't use the Most Correct Picks.
In the case of multiple correct Tie Breakers, a simple "?" would work.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365 we can use SORTBY then TAKE the top result:

```
=TAKE(SORTBY(A2:A9,ABS(C2:C9-C10),1,ABS(B2:B9-B10),1),1)
```

[image]

To get when the Tie Breaker also is the same then we can use:

```
=LET(
    nme,A2:A9,
    tb,B2:B9,
    c,C2:C9,
    atb,B10,
    ac,C10,
    r,FILTER(HSTACK(nme,tb),ABS(c-ac)=MIN(ABS(c-ac))),
    FILTER(TAKE(r,,1),ABS(TAKE(r,,-1)-atb)=MIN(ABS(TAKE(r,,-1)-atb))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly as soon as I resolved some formatting issues. When I merged two cells to hold the name of the player and did the same for the Tie Breaker, the formula seemed to get confused about which were the targets. I reformatted those cells to both be on the same row and it works just fine. Thank you!